# Rewrite long if statement to be more consice

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there better to write this long if statement? The only thing that changes is the `d=...` in the condition.

```
<%
if (
Request.Url.ToString().Contains("d=36423")
|| Request.Url.ToString().Contains("d=39252")
|| Request.Url.ToString().Contains("d=39280")
|| Request.Url.ToString().Contains("d=39251")
|| Request.Url.ToString().Contains("d=39246")
|| Request.Url.ToString().Contains("d=39245")
|| Request.Url.ToString().Contains("d=39244")
|| Request.Url.ToString().Contains("d=39243")
|| Request.Url.ToString().Contains("d=39242")
|| Request.Url.ToString().Contains("d=39241")
|| Request.Url.ToString().Contains("d=39240")
|| Request.Url.ToString().Contains("d=26009")
|| Request.Url.ToString().Contains("d=39239")
|| Request.Url.ToString().Contains("d=39238")
|| Request.Url.ToString().Contains("d=39237")
|| Request.Url.ToString().Contains("d=38816")
)
{%>

<div class="page-desktop-nav">

  <%} else {%>
  <div class="mobile-nav">
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 2):

you could store the values in an array and use something like the following:

```
<%  
var arr = new string[]
  {
    "36423",
    "39252",
    "39280",
    "39251",
    "39246",
    "39245",
    "39244",
    "39243",
    "39242",
    "39241",
    "39240",
    "26009",
    "39239",
    "39238",
    "39237",
    "38816"
  };

  string url = Request.Url.ToString();
  if (arr.Any(s => url.Contains(string.Format("d={0}", s)))) {
%>
```

Comment: A HashSet would be better than an array. `Contains()` would be an O(1) instead of O(n)

Comment: I get error on this : Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `Any()` is an extension method of the `System.Linq` namespace, which you should add for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Request.QueryString["d"]` to find the value of the `d` parameter, then check if it's contained in an array or collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all decimal values in one array and in for loop you can write d=arr[i]

It will remove your multiple time write same line of code

Thanks.

Comment: Can I do it like this

`var arr = new string[]
  {
    "36423",
    "39252",
    "39280",
    "39251",
    "39246",
    "39245",
    "39244",
    "39243",
    "39242",
    "39241",
    "39240",
    "26009",
    "39239",
    "39238",
    "39237",
    "38816"
  };`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add these extension methods to your library:

```
static public class ExtensionMethods
{
    static public bool ContainsAny(this string input, IEnumerable<string> searchFor) 
    {
        return searchFor.Any( s => input.Contains(s) );
    }
    static public bool ContainsAny(this string input, params string[] searchFor) 
    {
        return searchFor.Any( s => input.Contains(s) );
    }
}
```

And use like this:

```
    if (request.Url.ToString().ContainsAny("d=36423","d=39252","d=39280,"etc."))
    {
    }
```

Or

```
    var lookup = new[] {"d=36423","d=39252","d=39280","etc"};
    if (request.Url.ToString().ContainsAny(lookup))
    {
    }
```